# Forcing Homebrew and Macports to coexist?

Tags: macos, macports, homebrew

I have a MacOSX system that I've been using for a number of years, and during this time, I have installed quite a few packages via Macports.

I now want to try Homebrew, but it's clear from what I've read here and elsewhere that the default installations of Homebrew and Macports cannot easily coexist.

It is not a viable option for me to uninstall Macports, since so much of my daily MacOSX work involves using various Macports-installed utilities. Furthermore, many of my own, homegrown utilities are now interdependent with Macports. And finally, a lot of executables and shared libraries that I routinely use are now installed under /usr/local, and my system would quickly become unusable if I cleared out that directory tree.

So my question is this: has anyone come up with an alternate way to install Homebrew which can coexist with Macports? Specifically, has anyone figured out how to make Homebrew utilize a directory tree such as /usr/local/homebrew instead of /usr/local?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers to docs.

Comment: If you just want to try, why not set up an OS X virtual machine? It's not against Apple's TOS for OS X 10.7 and you can experiment with whatever you want there. Even if it kind of works to use both in parallel, I wouldn't be surprised if things started breaking...

Comment: Thank you very much, but I prefer to get both package managers running in the same OSX environment, if there is any way at all to do that. This is because if I like Homebrew, I will then want to gradually install packages via that system and gradually uninstall the old Macports-based packages. Unfortunately, it isn't a viable alternative for me to decide on Homebrew, blow away all my legacy Macports code in one fell swoop, and then struggle to replace it all in another fell swoop via Homebrew.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Homebrew to use its own directory, and then add that to the path. Although not for the same purpose, this excerpt from the installation guide tells it:

> Multiple installations
>
> Create a Homebrew installation wherever you extract the tarball.
>   Whichever brew command is called is where the packages will be
>   installed. You can use this as you see fit, e.g. a system set of libs
>   in /usr/local and tweaked formulae for development in ~/homebrew

Source: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation

Comment: Thank you Karolos. I'm not encouraged by the following statment on that same wiki page: "However do yourself a favor and install to /usr/local ... _Pick another prefix at your peril!_" But I'll give this a try and report back later.

Comment: I have tried to install homebrew in /usr/local/homebrew. However, a number of packages that I try to install are failing. When I run **/usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew doctor**, I get references to literally dozens of unexpected dylibs, static libraries, .pc files, and .la files, plus warnings about certain packages requiring a /usr/local installation. Since my system won't run at all if I blow away my legacy software installations (which is where most of those "unexpected" files are coming from), it looks like there is no way for me to use homebrew on my system. Oh well ... (sigh) ...

Comment: @HippoMan: Sorry that it doesn't work out. One question though: is /usr/local/homebrew correctly set up in your paths? i.e. PATH and (DY)LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @HippoMan: Which packages are failing ? I just tried install a couple of them and didn't see any problem (after editing /etc/paths to add /usr/local/homebrew/bin).

Comment: Yes, I have PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH set up correctly to point to bin and lib under the /usr/local/homebrew tree. One of the packages that failed is gawk, which is a prerequisite for avidemux. But I will restart from scratch and try one more time, in case I made some sort of error.

Comment: ... and it failed again in the same way. I get this error: **Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_history_list"**.

Comment: Could you give details on your system ? I just did `brew install gawk` and it worked like it should. I'm using 10.7.2, however, recently installed. Edit: For avidemux I get "Error: No available formula for avidemux".

Comment: I'm using 10.7.2, also. The fact that the gawk build works for you but not for me is almost certainly due to the legacy software that I have installed, which illustrates the exact problem that I am describing here. If you want to try avidemux, go here for instructions: [link](http://www.avidemux.org/smf/index.php?topic=9960.msg53651#msg53651). They have a homebrew formula there for avidemux.

Comment: @HippoMan: I'm sorry that it doesn't work for you. I have MacPorts, Fink and Homebrew happily co-existing on my machine; but as I said, it's a relatively new install. One thing: I'm _not_ running as sudo, but as my regular user instead. Good luck! If you can afford it, you could re-install OS X.

Comment: I'm revisiting this, in case anyone might provide some new insights. Re-installing OSX is not an option for me ... at least not a viable option, given all of my legacy code. Unless some new information is presented (which I hope!), it looks like I cannot use Homebrew at all under my current environment. It would be nice if the Homebrew people would figure out a way to get it to work reliably in all cases under something other than /usr/local. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My way to force them coexist is to make MacPorts not visible by default, but visible when invoking any MacPorts programs. That is, wrap MacPorts programs with some script like:

```
if [ "$#" -le 0 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 command [arg1, arg2, ...]" >&2
  exit 1
fi
if [[ -z $MACPORTS_PREFIX ]]; then
  MACPORTS_PREFIX='/opt/local'
fi
export PATH="$MACPORTS_PREFIX/bin:$MACPORTS_PREFIX/sbin:$PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MACPORTS_PREFIX/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export CPATH="$MACPORTS_PREFIX/include:$CPATH"
command=$1
shift
exec $command $*
```

If you name this script as `macports.sh`, you can do the wrapping by `macports.sh macports_bin`, such as `macports.sh port` will run `port` wrapped.

For convenience, you can put `macports.sh something` into some scripts with the same name as the commands themselves and put them in your HOME directory, such as `~/bin`, `~/.local/bin`, etc.

I've written [a blog post](http://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/10/23/use-both-homebrew-and-macports-on-your-os-x/) about this one month ago. You can read it if you need a look into the details.